# how do i merge two audio files and one video file in to a video file using c#?

Tags: c#, video, audio, merge

i wrote a program in c# using directshow , that captures all devices' audios , and video from single device (webcam or external camera) , now that my requirement is to merge selected audio files with one video file and i can not get it done in c#.
so i need a program or libraries that merges one(or several) audio file(s) and one video file and save it as an avi VIDEO file ,, both audio file  and video files are in avi format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this out [A Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx)

Comment: Awesome man, thanks , its working ... thanks a lot, more questions .. coming up ;)